# Google Scripts: XML parsing errors

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I have a google script that locates a specific .zip folder on a server, extracts the files, and takes a specific .xml file to be processed. My problem is getting this file into the proper format.

The applicable snippet of code:

```
  var dir = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var b = dir.getBlob();
  var files = Utilities.unzip(b);
  var vesselDataBlob;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName().equals("dat/vesselDataMod.xml")) {  //finds file with appropriate name
      vesselDataBlob = files[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  var vesselData = vesselDataBlob.getDataAsString(); // Returns FULL document as a string.
  var data = XmlService.parse(vesselData); // Throws error.
```

vesselData is in xml format, and `vesselData.getContentType()` returns "text/xml".

However, I'm struggling to find a way to parse the data. `XmlService.parse(vesselData)` throws an error: "Content is not allowed in prolog." I tried using DOMParser, which also throws an error. Is there something wrong with how I've set up my code? Is the data not actually in xml format?

The obvious difference between what most people probably do and my situation is that I'm pulling a file from a zipped folder, instead of just straight from a website. That's not the problem, I've tried just using a xml file uploaded to Drive, and the same problem occurs.

I can set up string manipulation to get the data I need, but I'd rather not go through the effort if someone can help out. Thanks!

I've been using this snippet of xml for debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vessel_data version="2.1">
    <hullRace ID="0" name="TNS" keys="player">
        <taunt immunity="Yadayada" text="More yadayada"/>
    </hullRace>
</vessel_data>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function works for me with a very simple zip file.  I recommend that you try getDataAsString("UTF-8") and see if that resolves the issue.

```
function test() {
  var f = DriveApp.getFilesByName("ingest.zip").next();
  var files = Utilities.unzip(f.getBlob());
  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var ff = files[i];
    if (/\.xml$/.test(ff.getName())){
      var s = XmlService.parse(ff.getDataAsString());
      Logger.log(s);
      s = XmlService.parse(ff.getDataAsString("UTF-8"));
      Logger.log(s);      
      break;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is pretty much exactly the same as what I already have. I did try getDataAsString("UTF-8"), although UTF-8 is the default, and it changed nothing. Could it have something to do with the .zip file being on an external server instead of on Drive?

Comment: I did also check that `/\.xml$/.test(ff.getName())` was true, and it is with my current code.

Comment: I do not know.  Hopefully someone else can offer some insight here.  I presume that you have verified that the xml file in the zip is valid.  What happens if you try to parse a simpler xml file within a zip.

Comment: I tried uploading a short xml file onto google drive, without dealing with the zipped folder, and it produces the same error: "Content is not allowed in prolog."

Comment: Could you paste your sample xml (or a link to a gist containing the xml)?

Answer (score 0):

I put your XML file into a gist (as XML, not zip) and it parses.

```
function test2() {
  var f = UrlFetchApp.fetch("...gisturl.../test.xml").getBlob(
);
  var s = XmlService.parse(f.getDataAsString());
  Logger.log(s.getDescendants().length);      
}
```

Unfortunately, I am now having trouble getting Utilities.unzip() to run on a zip file uploaded to Google Drive.  Hopefully another user will give you a better solution.

Comment: Fixed that, but still no luck :/

Comment: I tried `Logger.log(file.getAs("text/xml"));` and that gave me an error: "Converting from application/octet-stream to text/xml is not supported." I'm not sure what octet-stream is... That might be related.

Comment: Nope, that was unrelated and me losing track of things.